# Does the Black Mesa mod for Half-Life 2 work with Episode 2?

Tags: half-life-2, black-mesa

Does the Black Mesa mod for Half-Life 2 work with Episode 2? I couldn't find any clear answer on the [mod page](http://www.moddb.com/mods/black-mesa).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  The Black Mesa mod is a high-def remake of Half Life 1.  That's it.  It uses the Source engine to do so; it's not a Half Life 2 mod, persay, as much as a total conversion.  Half Life 2 was used as the starting point, but is not at all required to play Black Mesa.

What the mod page DOES say is: `Play for FREE! You need not purchase anything!`, and classify it as a Half Life 2 mod.  This conflicts, and the correct answer is the bullet point.  Most likely, it was classified as a Half Life 2 mod because the database doesn't allow it to be blank.  A better place to look is the [official site](http://wiki.blackmesasource.com/General_FAQ#What_is_Black_Mesa.3F).

HL2 also uses the Source engine, but is in no way required to play Black Mesa.

Comment: Oh I see now. So the mod. is only for the Half-Life 1 game, and I also wanted to know does this mod. only work for the main game or will it also work for Opposing Force/Blueshift?

Comment: ...What are you asking?  I think you're missing something in what the mod does.  It just allows you to play HL1 with upgraded textures.  It does absolutely nothing at all to HL1, 2, or anything else using the Source engine.

Comment: I understand that. I mean does this mod. also "upgrade" textures for Opposing Force/Blueshift or does the modification not effect those at all? I'm confused.

Comment: Nope.  It does nothing at all to anything else.  It's not an "upgraded textures" mod.  It's a total conversion with a specialized focus: remaking Half Life 1.  That's it, that's all.

Comment: I'm still unclear, but thanks for trying anyway.

Comment: You're looking at it as a mod that upgrades Half Life 1 textures.  That's not what it is, or does.  Half Life 1 was completely remade, using the Source engine.  In essence, Black Mesa is it's own separate game entirely.  It's being classified as a mod, but it actually isn't.

Comment: Black Mesa is essentially a remake of HL1 using the Source engine, which is what powers HL2 and the episodes, as well as some other Valve games.  Story and basic level design come from HL1, but that's about it.  All assets in Black Mesa either come from HL2 (although they're packaged with Black Mesa), or were created from the ground up.  The reason it's classified as a mod is because you need a (free) Source engine game or utility.

Comment: "It should be noted that the project is being built from the ground up and is not a simple port of Half Life maps and models into the Source Engine. The idea is to remake the storyline used in Half Life into a new polished Source Engine version with new models, maps, soundtrack, voice acting and textures." _OH now_ I see what you're getting at. It's not just a visual upgrade, this is a case of RTFM on my part. Anyway I'll just go ahead and play the original HL1 so I don't get lost. Thanks, and to you too @MBraedley

Comment: It's worth adding that it used to be that you needed to have some Source game in order to play early versions of it.  You now only need the Source SDK Base 2007 tool installed which you can do without owning any source game.

Answer (score 4):

From [this page](http://wiki.blackmesasource.com/General_FAQ#What_I_need_in_order_to_play_Black_Mesa.3F)

> The only requirement to play Black Mesa is to have Source SDK Base 2007
>   installed on Steam.  If you don't have it installed when you try to launch
>   Black Mesa, Steam will download it for you

Also, according to the [Half Life 2: Episode 2 Steam Page](http://store.steampowered.com/app/420/), the game "Includes Source SDK"

So yes, owning Half Life 2: Episode 2 (and ONLY that game) gives you access to Source SDK and thus, able to play the Black Mesa mod.